# Ruby Learning - Know of any public repos with Ruby code of Intermediate difficulty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github

I've been going through Ruby (and Ruby on Rails) tutorials online such as [RubyMonk](http://rubymonk.com/), [Codeschool](http://www.codeschool.com/) courses, the [Railstutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/), and [Learn Ruby the Hard Way](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/).

These are all excellent resources, but I feel like I need to see some Ruby code that is actually being used in production in order to advance to the next level.  I would assume that a repo like Rails would be considered advanced level - so I'm looking for something a little in-between.

**Are there some GitHub public repos that are using a more intermediate difficulty level of Ruby coding that I can learn from?**

If you can recommend some that would be an appropriate follow-up based on the contents of the tutorials I listed earlier, that would be great.

I've looked some myself, but I'm asking for recommendations because I want to make sure I'm studying something that is "the right way" to do Ruby and not learning bad habits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's two I've created:

- http://github.com/rails3book/ticketee - A light-weight project management system from the http://manning.com/katz'>Rails 3 in Action book.
- http://github.com/radar/forem - A forum engine for Rails 3 applications.

Both should have pretty good examples of intermediate code, along with tests.

Comment: Thanks very much, these will definitely keep me busy.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I published **[a solution to a ThoughtWorks interview problem](https://github.com/fj/thoughtworks-sales-tax)** that I used as the example for a talk. I'm not sure it's "intermediate", but quite a few things in there might fall outside the range of "beginner", so I think it might be up your alley. There's also a rather robust test suite using `MiniTest::Spec` and `mocha`.

For example, I use this approach to cause classes which include a module to register themselves with their base class:

```
module TaxWorks
  module TaxStrategy
    def self.included(base)
      add_strategy base
    end

    def self.strategies
      @strategies ||= []
    end

    private

    def self.add_strategy(s)
      strategies << s
    end
  end
end
```

In this example, now you can do `TaxStrategy.strategies` to enumerate the list of possible strategies, after loading any you care about.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you're into Rails you should have a look at these open-source Rails apps:

- https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org - Source code for rubygems.org, the Rubygems server/website
- https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts - Source code for railscasts.com

Both of these apps are exceptionally well organized, clean and thought out. In the case of rubygems.org it's had tons of contributions from different rubyists and is a great working example of Rails in action.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) is a good start. Take a look at Sinatra's source code and build a small MVC application with some helpers.  You will not only learn some ruby but also get a good understanding for how Rails work without the magic. It is made "the right way" and you will not learn any bad habits.

Comment: Thanks - Learn Ruby the Hard Way finishes with a small Sinatra project.  I'll check out their repo.

Comment: Do you know why Sinatra project has so long file (more than 1000 lines)? I think it's not good example of pretty code. Am i right?

<< https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb